# Do self-answers count towards tag badges?

Tags: support, self-answer, tag-badges

If I ask and answer my own question, do the votes and answer count count towards a tag badge?

E.g., if I get an upvote for an answer to my own question, does that count towards the 1000 required for a gold badge? Does the answer count towards the 200 required?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

They do count towards the badge.

I was awarded a gold badge for the [support](/questions/tagged/support) tag here on Meta after reaching the prerequisite 200 non-CW answers. Among those 200 answers is *one* self-answer. I also had one [support](/questions/tagged/support) question (the one I answered) and one Community Wiki answer at the time.